# Find indices of vector elements in a list

Tags: r, list, vector

I have this toy character vector:

```
a = c("a","b","c","d","e","d,e","f")
```

in which some elements are concatenated with a comma (e.g. "d,e")

and a list that contains the unique elements of that vector, where in case of comma concatenated elements I do not keep their individual components.

So this is the list:

```
l = list("a","b","c","d,e","f")
```

I am looking for an efficient way to obtain the indices of the elements of `a` in the `l` list. For elements of `a` that are represented by the comma concatenated elements in `l` it should return the indices of the these comma concatenated elements in `l`.

So the output of this function would be:

```
c(1,2,3,4,4,4,5)
```

As you can see it returns index 4 for `a` elements: "d", "e", and "d,e"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a strategy with factors. First, find the index for each element in your list with

```
l <- list("a","b","c","d,e","f")
idxtr <- Map(function(x) unique(c(x, strsplit(x, ",")[[1]])), unlist(l))
```

This build a list for each item in `l` along with all possible matches for each element. Then we take the vector `a` and create a factor with those levels, and then reassign based on the list we just build

```
a <- c("a","b","c","d","e","d,e","f")
a <- factor(a, levels=unlist(idxtr));
levels(a) <- idxtr
as.numeric(a)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 4 4 5
```

finally, to get the index, we use as.numeric on the factor

Answer (score 2):

I would make your search vector into a set of regular expressions, by substituting the comma with a pipe. Add `names` to the search vector too, according to its position in the `list`.

```
L <- setNames(lapply(l, gsub, pattern = ",", replacement = "|"), seq_along(l))
```

Then you can do:

```
lapply(L, function(x) grep(x, a, value = TRUE))
# $`1`
# [1] "a"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "b"
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "c"
# 
# $`4`
# [1] "d"   "e"   "d,e"
# 
# $`5`
# [1] "f"
```

The `names` are important, because you can now use `stack` to get what you are looking for.

```
stack(lapply(L, function(x) grep(x, a, value = TRUE)))
#   values ind
# 1      a   1
# 2      b   2
# 3      c   3
# 4      d   4
# 5      e   4
# 6    d,e   4
# 7      f   5
```