# Find indices of vector elements in a another vector

Tags: r, list, vector

This extends [a previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728669/find-indices-of-vector-elements-in-a-list).
I have 2 vectors:

```
a <- c("a","b","c","d","e","d,e","f")
b <- c("a","b","c","d,e","f")
```

I created `b` from `a` by eliminating elements of `a` that are contained in other, comma separated, elements in `a` (e.g., "d" and "e" in `a` are contained in "d,e" and therefore only "d,e" is represented in `b`).

I am looking for an efficient way to map between indices of the elements of `a` and `b`.

Specifically, I would like to have a list of the length of `b` where each element is a vector with the indices of the elements in `a` that map to that `b` element.

For this example the output should be:

```
list(1, 2, 3, c(4,5,6), 7)
```

Comment: If you follow up from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24729159/1270695) at the previous question, you can just do `lapply(L, function(x) which(grepl(x, a)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying *slightly* from [my answer at your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24729159/1270695), try:

```
a <- c("a","b","c","d","e","d,e","f")
b <- c("a","b","c","d,e","f")
B <- setNames(lapply(b, gsub, pattern = ",", replacement = "|"), seq_along(b))

lapply(B, function(x) which(grepl(x, a)))
# $`1`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 2
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 3
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 4 5 6
# 
# $`5`
# [1] 7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way to achieve this more efficiently? The dimensions of my data are quite big and the lapply is taking very long.

Comment: @user1701545, It's not the `lapply` that is likely to be taking long, but having to use `grep/grepl` so many times. I would suggest you try to formulate a more comprehensive question that tries to show what you're really trying to solve and you might be able to get more appropriate suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your advice and posted the whole 'story' in a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730992/combining-rows-of-a-matrix-according-to-a-mapping-asssignment