# Combining rows of a matrix according to a mapping asssignment

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following type of matrix:

```
son.mat <- matrix(data = rep(rnorm(5), 9), nrow = 9, ncol = 5)
```

with these `rownames`:

```
rownames(son.mat) <- c("a1","a2","b","a3,a4","c","d1","e1","d2,e2,e3","f")
```

So some of the `rownames` are comma concatenated individual names.

I have a `data.frame` that maps the individual names to their parent names:

```
df <- data.frame(son.ids = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","b","c","d1","d2","e1","e2","e3","f"), parent.ids = c("A","A","A","A","B","C","D","D","E","E","E","F"))
```

What I'm looking for is an **efficient** way to create a matrix which combines all the son rows according to their parents. This would cover cases where a parent has only a single son, cases where several comma concatenated sons have only a single parent, and cases where comma concatenated sons have several parents. To be clearer about the last case - if son.mat has rows with son.ids of two different parents combined (in this example "d2,e2,e3", it indicates that "D" and "E" are not separate and therefore all rows supporting only "D" and/or only "E" should be combined together with those supporting "D,E".

Better exemplified, the output matrix will be:

```
parent.mat <- rbind(apply(son.mat[c(1,2,4),], 2, sum), son.mat[3,], son.mat[5,], apply(son.mat[c(6,7,8),], 2, sum), son.mat[9,])
```

With these `rownames`:

```
rownames(parent.mat) = c("A","B","C","D,E","F")
```

Comment: Your actual question should be how to make `son.mat` [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). After that the task becomes easy. Of course, your output should also be in a better format than what you suggest.

Comment: Why is there no "D" or "E" row?

Comment: Thanks for youe question Ananda Mahto. I tried to make the post clearer about this. If the son.mat has rows of parent "D,E" this indicates that "D" and "E" are not separate and therefore should be combined. Therefore all sons of "D", "E" and of course those supporting "D,E" should be combined under "D,E".

Comment: I think Roland's right: go back and build your "son" dataframe in a much more sensible way.  Using row or column names as a sorting (or dbase query) input is a bad idea, as your difficulty in doing so makes clear.  Instead, generate additional columns with appropriate attributes.